# The order of the composition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that we have a meromorphic function $f$ defined on a complex riemann surface $C$ and $g$ a holomorphic function from $C$ to $C$ such that the composition is well defined. Write $ord_{p}(f \circ g)$ as the order of the function $f \circ g$ in $p\in C$.

Using the order properties is there a way to express $ord_{p}(f \circ g)$ using $ord_{p}(g)$ and $ord_{g(p)}(f)$?